# Java keytool importkeystore and set alias

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keytool, jks

I try to import certificate and private key from p12 to keystore and set alias:

```
keytool -destalias point_4432 -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore MY_KEYSTORE.jks -srckeystore point_4432.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass pass123
```

but I get and error:

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: if alias not specified, destalias
> and srckeypass must not be specified

please, help, how to set alias in time export? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify both parameters (ensure you are only importing one cert.):

```
-alias "IMPORT_ALIAS" -destalias "YOUR_ALIAS"
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically it's saying that if you don't specify which key to import, you can't specify which alias you want for the key; it will import all keys.

Maybe it is a mistype and you are specifying `-destalias` twice instead of `-destalias` and `-srcalias`

Comment: sorry, I make a mistake, it's one

Answer (score 2):

the "srcalias" parameter uses "1"

```bash
keytool -importkeystore -srcalias 1 -destalias "DEST"
```